# Why does PHP not complain when I treat a null value as an array like this?

Tags: php, arrays, null

**Edit 2022**: This appears to be fixed as of PHP 7.4 which emits a notice.

---

In PHP, I have [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) set to report everything including notices.

Why does the following not throw any notices, errors or anything else?

```
$myarray = null;
$myvalue = $myarray['banana'];
```

Troubleshooting steps:

```
$myarray = array();
$myvalue = $myarray['banana'];
// throws a notice, as expected ✔

$myarray = (array)null;
$myvalue = $myarray['banana'];
// throws a notice, as expected ✔

$myarray = null;
$myvalue = $myarray['banana'];
// no notice or warning thrown, $myvalue is now NULL. ✘ Why?
```

It's possible it's a bug in PHP, or I'm just not understanding something about how this works.

Comment: PHP isn't really the most *logical* language when it comes to data types: http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/

Comment: I agree with @Blender:  it usually does what makes the most sense doing its best given what it knows.  This is frequently quite convenient as far as not bothering anyone with trivial errors.

Comment: Wow - I've worked with PHP for years and somehow never been bitten by this madness until today. A quick test reveals that this crazy design decision remains unchanged in PHP 7. :(

Comment: You can even do this: `<?php null['banana'];` and it's not an error. I guess it's the same thing as using a variable that holds a null value, but it just looks super odd. Like Mark, I've only run into this after using PHP for several years and I'm amazed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an active [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37676) started at 2006.

And in documentation it is a notice about this in [String](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) section.
[image]

Comment: That's great.  As far as I know that wasn't in the documentation when I wrote this (or maybe I missed it because it was in the strings section), so thank you to whoever added/submitted that.

Comment: For PHP 7.4, this now throws notices: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/notice-for-non-valid-array-container

Answer (score 10):

Usually, when you try to use a value of one type as if it were another type, either an error or warning gets thrown or "type juggling" takes place. For example, if you try to concatenate two numbers with `.`, they'll both get coerced to strings and concatenated.

However, as explained on [the manual page about type juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), this isn't the case when treating a non-array like an array:

> The behaviour of an automatic conversion to array is currently undefined.

In practice, the behaviour that happens when this "undefined behaviour" is triggered by dereferencing a non-array is that `null` gets returned, as you've observed. This doesn't just affect nulls - you'll also get `null` if you try to dereference a number or a resource.

Comment: Thanks Narf, missed that part of the Type Juggling page earlier.  You'd think that throwing a warning or notice would have been a helpful design choice on their part though, if encountering "undefined" behaviour.

Comment: Well, I'd prefer PHP to be a bit more strict as well, but ... that's a kind of an unique feature that I don't think they'd be willing to deprecate any time soon.

Comment: I wouldn't want them to deprecate anything, just throw a notice or warning in order to be consistent with other times you access a non-existent array index, and warn developers about a potential mistake.

Comment: There is no type juggling in the evaluation of `$myarray['banana']` (which is correctly exposed in this answer by quoting from the documentation). The PHP source code is the proof. The explanation and the link are provided by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23538711/4265352).

Answer (score 10):

There are three types which it might be valid to use the *array derefence* syntax on:

- Arrays
- Strings (to access the character at the given position)
- Object (objects implementing the ArrayAccess interface)

For all other types, PHP just returns the *undefined variable*.

Array dereference is handled by the [FETCH_DIM_R opcode](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ccf863c8ce7e746948fb060d515960492c41ed27/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#L1159), which uses [zend_fetch_dimension_address_read()](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ccf863c8ce7e746948fb060d515960492c41ed27/Zend/zend_execute.c#L1249) to fetch the element.

As you can see, there is a special case for NULLs, and a default case, both returning the *undefined variable*.

Comment: This is the correct answer, there is not type juggling on the evaluation of `$myarray['banana']`.

Answer (score 4):

As of PHP 7.4, this behavior how emits a Notice.
"Trying to access array offset on value of type null"

See the first item in this 7.4 migration page.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.incompatible.php

This recently struck one of my colleagues in the butt because he neglected to validate the result of a database query before attempting to access column data from the variable.

```
$results = $this->dbQuery(...)
if($results['columnName'] == 1)
{
    // WHEN $results is null, this Notice will be emitted.
}
```

And I just noticed @Glen's comment, above, citing the relevant RFC.
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/notice-for-non-valid-array-container