# php undefined index notice not raised when indexing null variable

Tags: php, arrays, undefined

I'm curious to know if the following behaviour in PHP is intended or not.  And, if it is intended, it is considered acceptable to initialize an array from a null variable by creating an index into it (as is done in the first code snippet)?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$arr = null;

echo ($arr["blah"]===null) ? "null" : $arr["blah"];

$arr["blah"] = "somevalue";
echo "<br>";
echo ($arr["blah"]===null) ? "null" : $arr["blah"];
var_dump ($arr);
```

This outputs

```
null
somevalue

array (size=1)
   'blah' => string 'somevalue' (length=9)
```

However, if the array is initialized first (see code below), I get the exact same output, but an "Undefined Index" notice is given when I first try `$arr["blah"]`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$arr = array();

echo ($arr["blah"]===null) ? "null" : $arr["blah"];

$arr["blah"] = "somevalue";
echo "<br>";
echo ($arr["blah"]===null) ? "null" : $arr["blah"];
var_dump ($arr);
```

Comment: It is intended, but highly disrecommended. It's a relic of the past, not anything that should be used in good code. Always initialize your variables before use.

Comment: You should look into the functions `isset()`, `is_null()`, and `empty()`. Welcome to loosely-typed, implicit almost-everything hell.

Comment: I may not be understanding this question fully, however when "assigning", one would use the `=` operator instead of checking as a conditional statement of `==` or `===` am I missing something here? IMO, you can't pass off a conditional as an `echo`

Comment: thanks, @WaleedKhan.  I normally initialize variables but realized I had forgotten this one but was surprised that when I was using it i wasn't getting an error or notice at least

Comment: I see what you're saying... `$arr["blah"]` is just coming out of nowhere in both cases but it only throws a notice when `$arr` is first set to an array. (Right? Or did I miss something too?)

Comment: @Fred-ii- those conditional checks are just for me for debugging to print out what's going on.  the question is about why one can assign a value to an index of a variable that is null.  Seems like a bad idea.  `$arr=null; $arr["index"] = "value";`

Comment: @susiederkins: This is because of how arrays in PHP work. See this: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying `If $arr doesn't exist yet, it will be created, so this is also an alternative way to create an array`.  So, when you do `$arr = null;`, to PHP it's the same as not defining `$arr` at all (maybe, I'm not 100% sure: https://eval.in/68610), so when you do `$arr["blah"] = "somevalue";`, it makes an array for you.

Comment: thanks @RocketHazmat.  if you your comment in an answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: @susiederkins: That still doesn't explain why you didn't get `Undefined Index` the 1st time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does PHP not complain when I treat a null value as an array like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990321/why-does-php-not-complain-when-i-treat-a-null-value-as-an-array-like-this)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Apparently, you can do this with boolean too, but not undefined variables (even though they var_dump as null): https://eval.in/68794 Type juggling doc page sort-of mentions this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: @Chris: It says: "The behaviour of an automatic conversion to array is currently undefined".  So, I guess that makes sense.

Comment: There is an open issue for a similar problem: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54155 ... Maybe you should post a comment on this topic.

Comment: @chris You are correct - it is addressed in that other post.  Please feel free to close this thread.  I don't appear to have privileges to do so.

Answer (score 2):

PHP won't attempt the comparison if the array is null.

In the second circumstance, a comparison does occur because the array is set. PHP does not check to see if it is empty.

Your ternary is attempting to access the variable $arr["blah"], not checking to see if it is set before doing a comparison.

The proper way to write this would be:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$arr = array();

if(isset($arr["blah"])) echo ($arr["blah"]===null) ? "null" : $arr["blah"];

$arr["blah"] = "somevalue";
echo "<br>";
if(isset($arr["blah"])) echo ($arr["blah"]===null) ? "null" : $arr["blah"];
var_dump ($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, John Vargo was correct. If a variable is `null`, accessing it as if it were an array will simply return `null` without notices. This will change in the upcoming 7.4 version, then it will produce a notice.

```
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

The actual output is still the same.