# use php NULL like array

Tags: php

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors',1);
  ini_set('error_reporting',-1);
  $data = null;
  var_export( $data['name']);
  echo PHP_EOL;
  var_dump($data['name']);
```

Why the result is null, but no notice or warning occured?

Comment: I haven't found anything in the documentation that explains the lack of an error for an undefined array index. Looks like [this PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68110) might be related?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does PHP not complain when I treat a null value as an array like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990321/why-does-php-not-complain-when-i-treat-a-null-value-as-an-array-like-this)

Answer (score 0):

Because null is an undefined type, `$data['name']` therefore creates its own array.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the data type of `$data` before assigning `null`, you will get the undefined variable notice.

```
echo gettype($data);
$data = null;
```

After you assigned `null` to `$data`, you will see `NULL` for its value and its data type.

```
$data = null;
echo gettype($data);
var_dump($data);
```

According to [the documentation of NULL](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php), you're getting `NULL` for `$data['name']` means that it has not been set to any value yet.

> The special NULL value represents a variable with no value. NULL is
>   the only possible value of type null.
>
> A variable is considered to be null if:
>
> - it has been assigned the constant NULL.
> - it has not been set to any value yet.
> - it has been unset().

The following two examples show that the previously defined variable is not auto-converting to array, and keep its original data type.

#### Example 1:

```
$data = null;          // $data is null
var_dump($data['name']); // null
var_dump($data[0]);    // null
```

#### Example 2:

```
$data = 'far';  // $data is string
$data[0] = 'b'; // $data is still string
echo $data;     // bar
```

Answer (score -1):

Just reread documentation about type casting in php.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

PHP is not so strict  as c/c++ or java  :-)