# Parsing Wikipedia API with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, wikipedia-api

I have a PHP script that retrieves the JSON result from the Wikipedia API and stores it in $json variable, then I json decode it into $data:

```
<?php

$q = htmlspecialchars(($_GET["q"]));

$url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srnamespace=0&srprop=snippet&format=json&callback=json&origin=*&prop=links|extracts|categories|images&srsearch=test';
$json = file_get_contents($url);

/*
print "<pre>";print_r($json);print "</pre>";
*/

$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo $data['query']['search'][0]['title'];
```

This retrieves the JSON file, but I am not able to work with it. I need to extract the Title tag and echoing it like this doesn't do anything.

```
echo $data['query']['search'][0]['title'];
```

Any idea how to correct my code to retrieve the following title tag:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a JSON file with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/how-can-i-parse-a-json-file-with-php)

Comment: That looks like it should've worked.

Comment: Exactly, I can't find what's wrong with the test. I've spent an hour on it already and I am just not getting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `&callback=json` from your URL. That's making a request for [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (ironic link to wikipedia). It wraps the response with a JavaScript callback function, so instead of just JSON you need in PHP, you're getting

```
/**/json(THE JSON HERE)
```

You can see it in the page source, even if it displays as JSON on the page. Those extra characters are making `json_decode` fail. That parameter is intended more for cross-domain requests from JS.

It looks like you're already accessing the resulting array properly with

```
echo $data['query']['search'][0]['title'];
```

You might think it would give you some kind of warning or notice when you try to access those array keys when `$data` is null, but [it won't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990321/why-does-php-not-complain-when-i-treat-a-null-value-as-an-array-like-this).

Comment: The JSON callback is for if you're making a cross domain request (it wraps the response with the callback function). Useful from within a client browser, but generally not needed for PHP API calls.

Comment: @circusdei Yes, I was just reading about that. I'm usually working on the PHP side, so wasn't familiar with it

Comment: I'll remove if you want to incorporate into your response :)

Comment: @circusdei it's JSONP, isn't it? Just making sure I'll be referring to the right thing

Comment: this is awesome, worked like a charm... I know one thing... it would take me forever to figure out without your help... you've really made my day

Comment: @Don'tPanic JSONP it is.